# Term used for payment of war damages

Tags: verbs

I just need to know the term for what people pay for the war.

Comment: Are you looking for *reparations*?

Answer (score 4):

[War reparations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_reparations):

> - War reparations are payments intended to cover damage or injury inflicted during a war. Generally, the term war reparations refers to money or goods changing hands, but not to the annexation of land.(Wikipedia)

[Reparations](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=reparation%20):

> - ***"compensation for war damaged owed by the aggressor"*** is attested from 1921, with reference to Germany, from French réparations (1919).

Etymonline